# module 'pytube' has no attribute 'YouTube'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

Does anyone know where I can add the 'YouTube' module to my package `pytube` because it keeps giving the error that there is no attribute. I have installed pytube with pip3 on python 3.6.9.

code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
```

Comment: @PedroLobito I added the code.

Comment: Do you have any script or folder on the same dir  named `pytube` or `YouTube` ? If so, rename it and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: @PedroLobito nope, there is only 1 file. But there are different versions of pytube. I am not sure but maybe I have to install the correct one? And do I have to use pip or pip3?

Comment: "_do I have to use pip or pip3?_" -  it depends on which python [environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) you are.

Comment: "_there is only 1 file_" -  what's the dir name where the "_file_" is located?

Comment: @PedroLobito the dir of the file is (on python anywhere)  `/myProject/`. It is in the first folder directly. Do I have to change that? Or do I have to move the location to my `venv`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try tube_dl.

```
pip install tube_dl
from tube_dl import Youtube
yt = Youtube('url')
yt.Formats()[0].download()
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your script is not saved with "pytube.py" it's a common error for a first try

Answer (score 0):

Before, run this code your need to do this:

**Try uninstalling all versions of pytube with this command:**

```
python -m pip uninstall pytube pytube3 pytubex
```

**And then reinstalling with this command**

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

Now run this code:

```
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube

link = input("Please, Enter Your Youtube Video URL:")
link = str(link)
youtube = pytube.YouTube(link)
youtube.streams.first().download()

print("Video Has Been Downloaded", link)
```

*For more check my git: [here](https://github.com/NowshadRuhan/Youtube-Video-Downloaded-With-Python)*